# Formating an mysql query based on different  user input

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

$searchParams is actually an array which -if all the options are turned on looks like this

```
[q] => 77 [enhanced] => Y [no_subjects] => Y [visible] => Y
```

the user can change it so that the enhanced option might or might not be turned on....etc...

depending on that the look of the array will change

```
[q] => 77 [enhanced] => N [no_subjects] => N [visible] => N
```

etc...

```
public function getWebBookBasicSearchByParams($searchParams){
            $q = $searchParams['q'];
            $fields = "`bw`.`id`,`bw`.`isbn`,`bw`.`book_title`,`bw`.`edited_by`,`bw`.`book_schedule_date`,`bw`.`downloaded_num`,`bw`.`visible_online`,`snr`.`subject_id`";
            $join= "LEFT JOIN {$this->_t_subjects_relations} snr ON (bw.id = snr.object_id and snr.type ='bookweb') ";
            $counter=0;
            $add="";
        if (isset($searchParams['q']) && !empty($searchParams['q'])) {

            if($searchParams['no_subjects'] == 'Y'){
                $add.= " snr.subject_id = NULL";
                $counter ++;
            }
            if($searchParams['enhanced'] == 'Y'){
                $add.= " MATCH(bw.description1,bw.about_the_book) AGAINST ('{$q}'IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
                $counter++;
            }
            if($searchParams['visible'] == 'Y'){
                $add.= " bw.visible_online = 1";
                $counter++;
            }
            if($searchParams['visible'] == 'N'){
                $add.= " bw.visible_online = 0";
                $counter++;
            }
            $inCopula = ($counter > 0) ? " AND" : " " ;
            $extCopula = ($counter > 0) ? "WHERE " : " " ;
        }

        $query = "SELECT {$fields} FROM {$this->_t_books_web} bw {$join}{$extCopula}{$add}";
```

with this code I get this $query

```
SELECT `bw`.`id`,`bw`.`isbn`,`bw`.`book_title`,`bw`.`edited_by`,`bw`.`book_schedule_date`,`bw`.`downloaded_num`,`bw`.`visible_online`,`snr`.`subject_id` FROM `books_web` bw LEFT JOIN `subjects_new_relations` snr ON (bw.id = snr.object_id and snr.type ='bookweb') 
AND snr.subject_id = NULL
MATCH(bw.description1,bw.about_the_book) AGAINST ('77'IN BOOLEAN MODE) bw.visible_online = 1
```

obviously it is wrong, and it should look like this

```
SELECT `bw`.`id`,`bw`.`isbn`,`bw`.`book_title`,`bw`.`edited_by`,`bw`.`book_schedule_date`,`bw`.`downloaded_num`,`bw`.`visible_online`,`snr`.`subject_id` FROM `books_web` bw LEFT JOIN `subjects_new_relations` snr ON (bw.id = snr.object_id and snr.type ='bookweb') 
**WHERE**(snr.subject_id = NULL **AND**
MATCH(bw.description1,bw.about_the_book) AGAINST ('77'IN BOOLEAN MODE) **AND** bw.visible_online = 1)
```

How would you modify the code above in order to get the desired mysql query, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an array to store all your criteria and use [`implode`](http://fr.php.net/implode) to aggregate them.

```
public function getWebBookBasicSearchByParams($searchParams){
                $q = $searchParams['q'];
                $where = array();
                $fields = "`bw`.`id`,`bw`.`isbn`,`bw`.`book_title`,`bw`.`edited_by`,`bw`.`book_schedule_date`,`bw`.`downloaded_num`,`bw`.`visible_online`,`snr`.`subject_id`";
                $join= "LEFT JOIN {$this->_t_subjects_relations} snr ON (bw.id = snr.object_id and snr.type ='bookweb') ";
                $counter=0;
                $add="";
            if (isset($searchParams['q']) && !empty($searchParams['q'])) {

                if($searchParams['no_subjects'] == 'Y'){
                    $where[] = "snr.subject_id = NULL";
                    $counter ++;
                }
                if($searchParams['enhanced'] == 'Y'){
                    $where[] = " MATCH(bw.description1,bw.about_the_book) AGAINST ('{$q}'IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
                    $counter++;
                }
                if($searchParams['visible'] == 'Y'){
                    $where[] = " bw.visible_online = 1";
                    $counter++;
                }
                if($searchParams['visible'] == 'N'){
                    $where[] = " bw.visible_online = 0";
                    $counter++;
                }
                $inCopula = ($counter > 0) ? " AND" : " " ;
                $extCopula = ($counter > 0) ? "WHERE " : " " ;
            }

            $query = "SELECT {$fields} FROM {$this->_t_books_web} bw {$join}{$extCopula} WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $where);
    }
```